# Position dots between buttons in slick slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slick.js

I want to position the dots of the slick slider between the prev and next button.
Slick provides settings to let you position the dots/buttons. But they will show after each other.

This is my code:

```
$('.slider').slick({
    arrows: true,
    prevArrow: '<button type="button" class="slick-prev"> <- </button>',
    nextArrow: '<button type="button" class="slick-next"> -> </button>',
    appendArrows:$('.slider-controls'),
    dots: true,
    appendDots:$('.slider-controls'),
});
```

It generates the controls like this:

```
<div class="slider-controls d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
    <button type="button" class="slick-prev slick-arrow" style=""> &lt;- </button>
    <button type="button" class="slick-next slick-arrow" style=""> -&gt; </button>
    <ul class="slick-dots" style="" role="tablist">
        <li class="slick-active" role="presentation"><button type="button" role="tab" id="slick-slide-control00" aria-controls="slick-slide00" aria-label="1 of 3" tabindex="0" aria-selected="true">1</button></li>
        <li role="presentation" class=""><button type="button" role="tab" id="slick-slide-control01" aria-controls="slick-slide01" aria-label="2 of 3" tabindex="-1">2</button></li>
        <li role="presentation" class=""><button type="button" role="tab" id="slick-slide-control02" aria-controls="slick-slide02" aria-label="3 of 3" tabindex="-1">3</button></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But I want/need it like this:

```
<div class="slider-controls d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
    <button type="button" class="slick-prev slick-arrow" style=""> &lt;- </button>

    <ul class="slick-dots" style="" role="tablist">
        <li class="slick-active" role="presentation"><button type="button" role="tab" id="slick-slide-control00" aria-controls="slick-slide00" aria-label="1 of 3" tabindex="0" aria-selected="true">1</button></li>
        <li role="presentation" class=""><button type="button" role="tab" id="slick-slide-control01" aria-controls="slick-slide01" aria-label="2 of 3" tabindex="-1">2</button></li>
        <li role="presentation" class=""><button type="button" role="tab" id="slick-slide-control02" aria-controls="slick-slide02" aria-label="3 of 3" tabindex="-1">3</button></li>
    </ul>

    <button type="button" class="slick-next slick-arrow" style=""> -&gt; </button>
</div>
```

I know I could position the buttons with CSS but there are a few reasons, that I need the HTML like this.

Is there any way?

Comment: Could you post your original HTML as well so that we could try to reproduce?

Comment: found the solution, see below. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution.
You could add the following code to use a specific button as lin

```
nextArrow: $('#next')
```

And then add your custom button with the ID:

```
<button type="button" class="slick-next" id="next"> <- </button>
```

Full code:

```
$('.slider').slick({
    arrows: true,
    prevArrow: $('#prev'),
    nextArrow: $('#next'),
    dots: true,
});

    <button type="button" class="slick-prev" id="prev"> -> </button>

    <div class="slider">
            <div>your content</div>
            <div>your content</div>
            <div>your content</div>
    </div>

    <button type="button" class="slick-next" id="next"> -> </button>
```

Comment: please see answer

Comment: Hello Cray thank you for answer in this code .slider init main html Could you guide me i am very close to this but i am not find element to slide. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello Cray , Could you please add more details of your codes? I have this problem – parastoo amini just now